# How to filter in angular with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Filtering a data in angular with regex expression but doesnot get any output i am filtering data by following way: "**trying to do exact match**"

```
$scope.filteredEntries = filterFilter($scope.data, {path:'^/$'})
```

And $scope.data has following

```
$scope.data = [{'id':1,'Name':'abc','path':'/'},
              {'id':2,'Name':'def','path':'/'},
              {'id':3,'Name':'xyz','path':'/abc/'}]
```

expected data afterfilter

```
[{'id':1,'Name':'abc','path':'/'},
{'id':2,'Name':'def','path':'/'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not supported like this, because it would be hard for framework to distinguish it from actual string `'^/$'`.

If you want exact match you can provide a [comparator parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) `true`:

```
$scope.filteredEntries = filterFilter($scope.data, {path: '/'}, true);
```

#### Demo 1: http://plnkr.co/edit/WwpToPlb7j3JakGPVyFx?p=preview

Another options is to use a function to filter objects:

```
$scope.filteredEntries = filterFilter($scope.data, function(obj) {
    return /^\/$/.test(obj.path);
});
```

Note, that regular expression should be `^\/$`, you need to escape `/` character. However for this specific task using regular expressions is overkill, you probably should go with the first option.

#### Demo 2: http://plnkr.co/edit/dqiOP2lkBx1OazwsSlw7?p=preview